# Prevent Null pointer exception and remain in same page on jsp page reload

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am using Struts2, JSP for web development. Whenever a form is submitted the Java action class after updating the Database returns `SUCCESS` or `ERROR`, I am rendering on home page, but when I reload that home page again then I am getting null pointer exception because the variables (which were to be set when form submit button is clicked and action was called) are null in the action class. I want if the page is reloaded it remains in the same page.

One solution that I came up with is `validate` method of `ActionSupport` where i can check if the variables are null or not. Are there some other solutions which are better than this as this solution is not clean.

Comment: Redirect to some action after submit and fetch values from db in there.

Comment: but using redirect I will lose the stack value which may contain error messages and If I use chain than the problem will persist. Also I need some of the values which that page contains.

Comment: Redirect only on success.

Comment: @UjjwalPrakash Why the method `execute` is in the action interface?

Comment: and what about the success message ? how can I fetch that ?

Comment: @RomanC I dint got u. Can you help me to know how the execute method will help me solve this problem ?

Comment: @UjjwalPrakash This not help and support site, you should ask an interesting question to get the answer.

Comment: ohh Sorry I was not aware that you have the changed the description of StackOverflow that only interesting questions should be posted here.

Comment: @UjjwalPrakash yes, otherwise such questions classified as off-topic and closed. Many of them don't have any answer because nobody want to post it.

Comment: My use case is like a page fetches the data from db and displays it. and the page allows to change those data to save them and i want to show the same page when i action is success and show new data, and success message else show error message. But when I refresh the page (after it gets rendered by the save action), it is Null pointer exception

Comment: In that case you can add some parameter to indicate that success message should be shown.